# Checkout link does not work

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I have just installed virtuemart 1.1.9 to my Joomla 1.5.12. It is OK for adding category and product. But I click to checkout link, i am redirected to the main page of my store. What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Erm - I believe VirtueMart 1.1.9 requires a much more up-to-date version of Joomla (although I have just checked and can't find a reference for this I am pretty sure VM releases are tied to minimum Joomla releases, especially if you want a trouble free life).

Latest version of Joomla 1.5.x is 1.5.25 and frankly anything before 1.5.15 anyone (and I do mean *anyone*) can reset your admin password and take over your site.

Also check that your MSYQL permissions allow the use of temporary tables - shared hosting often doesn't and it is a requirement of VirtueMart.